# Sort 2-Dimensional PHP Array By Date

Tags: php, arrays, date, sorting, compare

Say I have a PHP 2-d array with the following format:

```
$json =    [
          {"value": "New", "date": $date},
          {"value": "Open", "date": $date},
          {"value": "Close", "date": $date}
    ]

$array = json_decode($json);
```

If the date is a datetime in the format of m/d/Y, how do I sort the array elements by the earliest to latest date?

Comment: usort() with a callback that converts the m/d/Y strings to timestamps, then compares

Comment: have a look at strtotime http://www.php.net/strtotime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given data such as the following:

```
$json = '[ {"value": "New", "date": "06/21/2013"}, {"value": "Open", "date": "06/20/2013"}, {"value": "Close", "date": "06/22/2013"} ]';
$array = json_decode($json, TRUE);//array of objects, so set second parameter to TRUE
usort($array, function ($a, $b){
    return strtotime($a['date']) - strtotime($b['date']);
});
print_r($array);
```

That returns an array of arrays. If you want to leave it as an array of objects and reencode it as JSON, you can use the following:

```
$array = json_decode($json);
$ord = array_map(function($a) {return $a->date;}, $array);
array_multisort($ord, $array);
$json = json_encode($array);
```

Comment: @nshah - You're welcome. I'm updating in case you want an array of objects.